# How to include current page in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have create one spider which find `next_page` url on current page then follow and scrap it, again on that page spider search for `next_page` url and scrap it and so on. 
It works fine, only problem is it skip scrapping on page mentioned in `start_urls` Its always start Scrapy from next page. 
Its should start scraping from current page ie `start_urls` then follow next page.
I know I am missing something. Please help me to understand whats wrong with following spider.

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = "myspider"
  allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
  start_urls = [
      "http://www.example.com/category"
  ]
  rules = (
       Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="next_page"]',))
           , follow= True, callback='parse_item'),
  )

def parse_item(self, response):
    item = scrapy.Item()
    item['id'] = response.xpath('//td[@id="item_id"]/text()').re(r'ID: (\d+)')
    item['name'] = response.xpath('//td[@id="item_name"]/text()').extract()
    item['description'] = response.xpath('//td[@id="item_description"]/text()').extract()
    return item
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try renaming your `parse_item()` function to `parse_start_url()`, and rename the callback in the rule accordingly. This is an undocumented function that is called for the start urls in the `CrawlSpider`, so overriding it gives you the desired functionality.

You can just make the following assignment in your code to override the method:

```
parse_start_url = parse_item
```

This way, your code could look something like this:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = "myspider"
  allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
  start_urls = [
      "http://www.example.com/category"
  ]
  rules = (
       Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="next_page"]',))
           , follow= True, callback='parse_item'),
  )

def parse_item(self, response):
    # process your item here

parse_start_url = parse_item
```

Comment: Thanks Lawrence. I tried both option. First one ie renaming to `parse_start_url()` worked as expected. But another one ie. `start_requests` doesn't worked. I tried exactly same as code you provided (edited) but its still returns results from next page.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the callback parameter. Try it now.

Comment: its throw error `self._scrape(response, request, spider).chainDeferred(deferred)` after adding callback parameter

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test it, writing from my head. Use Request instead of FormRequest. Check the code now.

Comment: BTW I am accepting answer as First option works perfectly fine, Thanks. Please update second option if you find solution.

Comment: You need to update the callback on your rule. Are you talking about the first approach? Or the second?

Comment: First approach is working ie renaming `parse_item()` function to `parse_start_url()`

Comment: Is the second approach throwing an exception now?

Comment: Now in second approach, Its returns scrap results from first page only. ie. http://www.example.com/category.

Comment: The issue here is most likely that the results are being filtered out. Add this line to your `settings.py` file and try running the spider: `DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy.dupefilter.BaseDupeFilter'`. It will disable filtering globally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66384/discussion-between-lawrence-and-ganesh).

Comment: I modified `settings.py`, but still returns only first page results.